# How to handle https security warning in IE for selenium rc test on ie

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am getting a warning like this when testing with selenium rc on IE Browser.  Is there a command I can use to wait for it and click yes?  Changing the Trusted Sites is not an option.
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/images/elevdialog.JPG[image: sdfion here]

Answer (score 1):

What we do is leverage a freely available tool called [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) which can interact with the windows component object model.  If you are expecting the dialog you can invoke it with an exec and then proceed with selenium commands.  If you want to catch unexpected ones, what we do is execute our selenium commands in a thread and if they time out we then run autoit having it return 0 or 1 depending if it finds a dialog and take things from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to go into the IE Options and tweak the trusted sites so that it has those 2 sites. Once that has been done then you should be fine.